# C# XML from URL - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a URL end point that results in an XML document, I'm using this code to try and put the data in to a XML Document object.

```cs
    XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
    myDoc.Load("[my-URL-here-]");
```

However I get the following error: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

When I use the SAME code to try and get this URL https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml (w3schools -sample)

I don't get the error

My URL's out put is this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

```xml
            <ArrayOfAutoCompleteResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mysite.Services">
            <AutoCompleteResult>
                <BrandName>Trazodone</BrandName>
                <Name>Trazodone Hydrichloride</Name>
                <ParentId>11403</ParentId>
            </AutoCompleteResult>
            <AutoCompleteResult>
                <BrandName>LysaKare</BrandName>
                <Name>Arginine/Lysine</Name>
                <ParentId>11403</ParentId>
            </AutoCompleteResult>
            </ArrayOfAutoCompleteResult>
```

So why does the sample W3schools URL work and mine dosen't.

Comment: Does your URL output start with "This XML file..."?  If so, that's not valid XML which is what the error is indicating.  The W3Schools XML starts with <note>.

Comment: Missing space in the first line of XML near `xmlns`

Comment: @JayBuckman no its the browser header - just like the w3schools one

Answer (score 1):

I got the below error with your xml.
System.Xml.XmlException: ''xm' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 79.'
You must have a space between the first and second xmlnsp attributes. Try the below xml. It works for me.

```
<ArrayOfAutoCompleteResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mysite.Services">
  <AutoCompleteResult>
    <BrandName>Trazodone</BrandName>
    <Name>Trazodone Hydrichloride</Name>
    <ParentId>11403</ParentId>
  </AutoCompleteResult>
  <AutoCompleteResult>
    <BrandName>LysaKare</BrandName>
    <Name>Arginine/Lysine</Name>
    <ParentId>11403</ParentId>
  </AutoCompleteResult>
</ArrayOfAutoCompleteResult>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, something happened when I did a copy and paste.... the space is there, so its not that.